# Book about a boy who accidentally hatches dragons at his grandparents' estate

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

I read a book in 2017, I think; it was about a boy who, for the summer had to go to his grandparents estate in the forest.

I remember it was huge with gargoyles on the front gate. He finds a really tall wall surrounding an area and tries to find his way in. He gets in and does some things and accidentally hatches dragons.

His grandfather stayed in an observatory, and most rooms had no furniture.

I think the book had a blue dragon on the cover.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be *[The Boy Who Grew Dragons](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/39355816-the-boy-who-grew-dragons)* (2018) by Andy Shepherd and Sara Ogilvie...?

[image]

Synopsis from Goodreads:

> When Tomas discovers a strange old tree at the bottom of his grandad's garden, he doesn't think much of it. But he takes the funny fruit from the tree back into the house - and gets the shock and delight of his life when a tiny dragon hatches! The tree is a dragonfruit tree, and Tomas has got his very own dragon, Flicker ...
>
> Tomas soon finds out that life with Flicker is great fun, but also very ... unpredictable. Yes, dragons are wonderful, but they also set fire to your toothbruth and leave your pants hanging from the TV aerial. Tomas has to learn how to look after Flicker - and quickly. And then something extraordinary happens - more dragonfruits appear on the tree. Tomas is officially growing dragons ...

This book was apparently part of a series, and [one of the later books](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/52271876-the-boy-who-dreamed-of-dragons) had a blue dragon on the cover.

Comment: If this answer is correct, please upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark just beneath the voting arrows.

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of [Pillage by Overt Skye](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2775759-pillage)?

> Upon his mother's death, fifteen-year-old Beck Phillips is sent to live with an eccentric uncle he had never met in a remote manor house, where he learns that his family suffers from a curse that allows him to make plants grow on command and dragon eggs hatch

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please [edit] your answer to include some evidence for why this book fits what the OP described. Answers are more helpful if they're self-contained, supported by external links but not *just* consisting of a link. We have a [guide on how to write a good story-ID answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9445/31394).

Answer (score 1):

Might it have been 'Jeremy Thatcher, Dragon Hatcher' by Bruce Coville? A slightly older kids book that I read too long ago to remember the details of, but seems a good candidate.[image]